# Structure/object versus material/aggregate in category theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there an analogue in category theory of the distinction between structures/objects and material/aggregate, a distinction reflected in the grammar associated with count and non-count nouns in English?

This question is motivated by the related comments in the post "[Spivak on Category Theory](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/03/spivak_on_category_theory.html)" at the n-Category Cafe. A discussion of the intricacies of the linguistic classification is given in [this post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/reference-for-a-standard-systematic-conceptual-categorization-of-count-and-non).

---

The paper by Reyes et al. cited in the blog post and below doesn't, to me, capture the essence of everyday intuition guiding distinctions between countable nouns (CNs) referring to countable structures/objects and uncountable mass nouns (MNs) referring to substances/materials (of which structures are made). Substances are quantified by 'volume' or weight (or number of actual or potential containers--ingots, tanks, cups, etc.) rather than count.

The paper states:

*The usual way of distinguishing MNs from CNs is by specifying semantical properties that MNs have but CNs lack.*

*Two or more dogs do not together constitute a larger dog; whereas two or more quantities of matter together constitute a larger quantity of matter. It is customary, following Quine [18, p91], to refer to this property of the
extension of MNs as cumulative reference.*

. . .

*The transformations mentioned before between CNs and MNs are described by functors. One example is the plural formation that takes the CN ‘dog’ into ‘dogs’. Since the extension of this term obviously has the property of cumulative reference, we categorize ‘dogs’ as a MN.*

I would not say that 'the dogs', referring to a specific group of dogs, has a cumulative reference and I can certainly count the members of any actual group or groups of dogs. Only 'dogs' as a class of animals as in 'Dogs are sociable' has a MN quality as in 'Liquids are fluid' and an associated syntax in English.

Examples that don't seem to fit the scheme: A 'drop of water' suspended in the air in an environment without gravity has a cumulative (and divisive) reference--I can easily add another drop to obtain a single larger drop (and divide it into smaller drops) yet it's regarded by most people, I believe, as a structure and, therefore, a countable entity/CN and not an uncountable MN, plural or otherwise. Same for a 'pile of sand" (or coins) or a 'line of sand' (or coins). If I add (accumulate) other piles or lines in a suitable way, I maintain a single line or pile yet a pile/piles or a line/lines are regarded as countable structures rather than an uncountable substance. This is in contrast to the discussion of 'dog' as a CN with no cumulative reference--adding dogs doesn't give you a larger dog (nor does dividing give you two smaller dogs, except in reproduction).

Consequently, my cursory review of the paper leaves me skeptical, but I found it thought-provoking, motivating me to ask if the notion of structure versus substance has been categorified (though this wouldn't be suficient to understand all countable versus noncountable nouns, e.g, shirts versus pants, shorts, eyeglasses, or scissors, which are counted as 'pairs of'.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but for a category-theoretic analysis of count nouns versus mass nouns, you might be interested in [Count nouns, mass nouns and their transformations: a category-theoretic unified semantics](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.6819&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Reyes, Reyes, and Zolfaghari.

Comment: Yes, that ref is in the post (in your comments there?). Not sure whether it emphasizes the distinction between objects and materials or just the linguistic machinery that flags the distinction in English.

Comment: Haha! I had not clicked your link, but who knew that I'd be pointing out the same literature on this topic 8 years later! At any rate, it sounds like you have something more specific in mind than I'm able to pick up on from the question as you've stated it. Tentatively, I might suggest that category theory tends to treat these things on an equal footing. Compare, for instance the fundamental groupoid of a space $X$ -- a category whose objects are _points_ of $X$ -- with the frame open sets of $X$ -- a category whose objects are in some sense the "parts" of $X$.

Comment: If so, seems category theory would have serious limitations in elucidating the use of metaphor in cognition.

Comment: Btw, Japanese have no trouble distinguishing between materials and objects. They just don't flag it in their grammar.

Comment: Surely if there is a place to look for an analogue of the count/non-count distinction it must be measure theory, not category theory?

Comment: A rough analogy: In topoloy in 3-D, a flat, bounded, compact, simply-connected 2-D surface with no holes is rubberlike. It is given no particular boundary structure. It is the material from which you can construct a torus, an object with two holes.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between metaphor and count vs. mass nouns, but do note that the ability to treat either "masses" or "countable things" as objects of (different) categories is central to the approach of Reyes et al, because they can set up adjunctions between these categories to compare them systematically. So I don't see it as a drawback that the distinction between masses and coutable things is not something built into category-theoretic language at a fundamental level.

Comment: Well, since you are a little shy about clicking links, it's understandable that you would not find my statements understandable.

Comment: @TomCopeland If your strategy for getting an answer to your philosophy / linguistics question is to ask it on a math forum, and if you expect the mathematicians you're talking to to read up on the non-mathematical background themselves, then it's understandable that you would not find your question to be answered to your satisfaction...

Comment: Actually, about ten years ago when I first started asking questions on MO, I used the term 'polytope' and was immediately asked by a user with a very high rep count what that term meant, so I had to include a link. (The comment has since been removed.) Consequently, when I ask my questions, I keep my expectations minimal and let the conversation play out according to the temperaments of those engaged, pretty much as in any field of thought.

Comment: There are many claims about the utility of category theory. This question is about a specific use and whether it is enlightening or not.

Comment: @ZhenLin, Like most people I have no problem intuitively distinguishing between substances and objects in the everyday world without the use of mathematics or even language. The question is really whether CT can inform on these topics significantly.

Comment: My view is that it does not. Then again, I tend to be a sceptic regarding applications of deductive mathematics to semantics of natural languages.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I suspected as much.

Comment: I have voted to close as unclear after the edit -- I am not a downvoter and I think this is an interesting question, but the answer by Tim is more than I'd imagined would exist on this topic. If it isn't what you're looking for, I think it would be appropriate to narrow this down to a more precise, clearer mathematical objection -- 'if we apply the adjunction to [situation X], we get something that doesn't match natural semantics; here are the computations and their interpretations'. So far you've claimed a few specific circumstances, but I think working out the details of them would help.

Comment: There's massaging the data to fit fhe theory, and there's massaging the theory to fit the data.

Comment: For more data, see https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/224/is-the-countable-vs-mass-noun-distinction-common-outside-english

Answer (score 1):

The [work of Reyes et. al.](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.6819&rep=rep1&type=pdf) directly addresses the metaphysical distinction underlying the linguistic distinction between mass nouns and count nouns, from a categorical perspective. Therefore, regardless of whether you're looking for a categorico-linguistic analysis or a categorico-metaphysical analysis, it completely answers your question as stated. If it doesn't answer the question you intended to ask, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I have trouble fitting a pile of sand, a pile of coins, a line of sand, a line of coins, a field of ... , or a drop of water suspended in the air in the space station into the scheme of Reyes et al. Perhaps you can enlighten me.

Comment: I only skimmed the paper, but it seems that they regard count nouns as sets, and mass nouns as sup-lattices. You have an free-forgetful adjunction between sets and sup-lattices, and phrases that involve both mass and count nouns (e.g. "this steak is meat") are interpreted by means of that adjunction. In the paper's proposed semantics, I imagine that a phrase like "a field of lines of piles of coins," involving multiple transitions between mass and count nouns, would simply require using that adjunction several times. (This begins to seem a bit like the bar construction.)

Comment: In this last comment on "a field of coins of lines of piles of coins" every noun refers to countable structures, not a single substance hence 'a field' = 'one unspecified field' and 'lines', 'piles', and 'coins' are in their plural forms. If the application of the category theory of the paper is correctly interpreted by the user, this is a singular failure of the theory in understanding (the English) language. I've never heard the phrase 'a field of water' rather than say 'a body of water'.